# Can't find the set of solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, absolute-value

Set of solutions of this inequality :

> $$\log_2({ \space x ^2 - 1}) < 1$$

The answer given is :$$ \sqrt3 < x < - 1 \cup 1 < x <  \sqrt3 . $$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead.

Comment: What are you asking for?

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_2(x^2-1)<1$$ it's
$$0< x^2-1<2$$ or
$$1<x^2<3$$ or
$$1<|x|<\sqrt3,$$  which gives your answer.